# Como remover o sombreamento (backdrop) de uma modal em Bootstrap e liberar a área restante da página?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou com dificuldades para remover aquela sombra que fica ao redor de uma modal Bootstrap. Com o código abaixo eu consigo remover:

```css
#myModal .modal
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Porém, não consigo manipular nada que está "atrás", mesmo estando oculto o `overflow`. A tela fica "liberada" (ocupa apenas o espaço da modal), mas não consigo, por exemplo, selecionar um texto que está na mesma página (fora do modal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado pela contribuição, mas não consegui da forma que indicou. Fiz assim:

```
#myModal.modal-backdrop{
    display: none;
    }

#myModal.modal{
    bottom: inherit;
    }
```

Funcionou dessa forma.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou... para exemplificar o que disse, coloquei neste [link](https://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/792/).

Comment: eu tinha colocado uma classe a mais no `modal-backdrop`, talvez foi isso que não funcionou... no exemplo já está certinho...

Comment: Obrigado @h3nr1ke

Answer (score 3):

para remover o fade que está atrás do modal

```
.modal-backdrop.in{
  display: none;
}
```

para habilitar novamente o overflow da página

```
.modal-open{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

para desabiltiar o click no modal, inclua na chamada de abertura do modal os parametros `backdrop` e `keyboard`

```
//desabilita o click fora e o fechar pelo esc
jQuery('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
```